# Using the GNU Scientific Library to Find the Kernel of a Matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, gsl, svd

Given a `gsl_matrix *` A object, which is an *M*-by-*N* matrix, what is the easiest way to find the kernel of A? I tried using singular value decomposition (specifically the [`gsl_linalg_SV_decomp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Singular-Value-Decomposition.html) method), but that doesn't work when *M*<*N*, which is sometimes the case for my matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way (if you are restricted to that library) would be to pad your matrix with rows of zeros to N x N, which you can then pass to your function. The padded matrix will have the same null space.